# MVVM - Adding Checkbox in header using AutoGenerateColumns on true

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I use the AutoGeneratingColumn event in my ViewModel to manage my columns creation, but I did not find a way to add a checkbox in each column's header.

Comment: When autogenerating, the checkbox is the cell template for bool properties. Column's header is something else, so you'll have to re-style it

Comment: Ok I get it, I've injected them using  `<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>` is that the right way to do it ? Yhx Natxo.

Comment: You can do it that way, specially when autogenerating. But note that it will apply to EVERY column header.

Comment: @Natxo Yes I saw that, what would be the proper way to make it work on some columns but not all ?

Comment: Use a template selector. Or forget autogenerating and edit desired columns header template.

Comment: @Natxo Ok thx Natxo, you solved the case.